# Magento Shopping Cart Rules

Tags: magento

I am looking for some help and advice with a shopping cart rules. The rule is as follows:

If they buy a particular product in any size or colour, they then receive a free product.

So far I have

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true: 
Category  is  884
```

But I am unsure how to do the last part. But I am not sure which would be the best way to do this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try out this [module](https://github.com/gaiterjones/magento-buy-x-get-y-free)

It may not work if you have already extended the cart controller class. If you dont know if you have just try it and see.